Weird conclusion from Willy Sansen's book about zeros and poles from Miller Capacitance in most basic analog amplifier
I have been reading "Analog Design Essentials" and I keep finding these weird graphs by the author. In this paragraph and image shown, he talks about influence of Miller capacitance on poles.

I understand that the BW is defined by the bigger time constant (\$C_{in}\cdot R_{in}\$ or \$C_{out}\cdot R_{out}\$) because that becomes the dominant pole.
I guess the next thing he does is that he shows this schematic where the input cap is \$\approx A_{v0}\cdot C_{DGt}\$ and output cap is just \$C_{L}\$ (i guess \$C_{L}>>(1-\frac{1}{A})\cdot C_M\$).
Earlier in the book, he uses \$V_{in}=\frac{V_{dd}}{2}\$, \$g_{m,1}=g_{m,2}\$ and \$r_{on,1}=r_{on,2}\$.
Also, he calculated \$A_{v0}=\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=2g_m\cdot R_{out} = g_m\cdot R_{on}\$ earlier in the book.
When I try to follow, I get this schematic for small-signal analysis:

which has extra \$A_{v0}\$ with the \$C_{DGt}\$ and has no zeros??
This is reeaaaaly unexpected and with the ever weirder graph with \$\frac{C_L}{g_m R_s}\$ line, i dont think any of this makes sense. Maybe, he wanted to show the frequency at which \$R_S\cdot A_{v0}\cdot C_M = R_{out}C_L\$ which can show which capacitance influences BW the most, but that turns out to be \$C_M = \frac{C_L}{2 g_m R_s}\$.
I mean, what? How can I be wrong here? Why did i get no zeros, different poles and whats with the graphs?

The Miller method removes the direct path between two given nodes and replaces it with two grounded impedances. So far, everything is intact, since the method is derived from basic circuit principles, KCL and KVL. However, the key point here is that the exact gain you must use in the formula is the frequency-dependent gain, \$ A(s) \$. If you replace that with the low-frequency gain, \$ A(0) \$, then the method becomes an approximation and fails to predict the zeros. The zeros show up if you use the exact expression for \$ A(s) \$ in calculating the two grounded (frequency-dependent!) impedances, which defeats the purpose of using the Miller method altogether.
As for the graphs, seems like the asymptotic behavior is plotted. That is why a factor two is missing. Note that the actual curve crosses through half of the knee point (the intersection of the two asymptotes), as also exemplified by the famous Bode plots.

in short, i should have used A(S) instead of Av0 to find A(S)? I don't get what you meant by "which defeats the purpose of using Miller method altogether", then what method i should have used, should I have solved it without using miller formula, but by just calculating with just Cdgt as is? What are the implications of this, is Miller formula always useless when calculating A(s)?

Well, if you wish to arrive at the exact transfer function using the Miller method, then you must use $A(s)$ because it merely uses principal circuit theorems. However, the Miller method is famous for its powerful simplification of floating impedances. When you use $A(0)$ and approximate the dominant pole and non-dominant pole using Miller, you save yourself a bunch of equations and the associated headache! However, the price you pay is you miss the zeros and your transfer function is approximate. In fact, you may even miss the intermediate poles if they are closely separated.

Cont'd: Thus, no, you should not use $A(s)$ because if you can already derive the exact $A(s)$, what is the point of using Miller? You must use the Miller theorem to simplify your circuit and arrive at the necessary information relatively rapidly while being aware of the shortcomings of such "shortcut" methods.

So your guess is that exact formula is used in the book completely unrelated to text, but mine is just an approximation so thats why i didn't get any zeros and slightly different poles?

The formula used in the figure is the exact derivation. You can play with the values of parameters and convince yourself that under certain conditions, it will reduce to more familiar versions. Whenever you use the Miller theorem, you have a (reasonably good) approximation to the answer with some limitaitons.
